# Remove numbers from alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, r

I have  a list of alphanumeric characters that looks like:

```
x <-c('ACO2', 'BCKDHB456', 'CD444')
```

I would like the following output:

```
x <-c('ACO', 'BCKDHB', 'CD')
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use `gsub` for this:

```
gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', x)
```

or

```
gsub('[0-9]+', '', x)
# [1] "ACO"    "BCKDHB" "CD"
```

Answer (score 16):

If your goal is just to remove numbers, then the `removeNumbers()` function removes numbers from a text. Using it reduces the risk of mistakes.

```
library(tm)

x <-c('ACO2', 'BCKDHB456', 'CD444') 

x <- removeNumbers(x)

x

[1] "ACO"    "BCKDHB" "CD"
```

Comment: Please format your answer and provide information about how your answer is better than the ones that were already posted. Also: Just code usually isn't enough. Can you explain what your solution does?

Answer (score 15):

Using [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html)

Most stringr functions handle regex

[str_replace_all](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) will do what you need

```
str_replace_all(c('ACO2', 'BCKDHB456', 'CD444'), "[:digit:]", "")
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer for most people.

Comment: str_remove_all from stringr would do this identically without needing the 3rd argument

Answer (score 6):

A solution using [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html):

```
# your data
x <-c('ACO2', 'BCKDHB456', 'CD444')

# extract capital letters
x <- stri_extract_all_regex(x, "[A-Z]+")

# unlist, so that you have a vector
x <- unlist(x)
```

Solution in one line:

[image: Screenshot on-liner in R]

Comment: Is a nice solution, however I have state names with footnotes (that I want to remove) and by "District of Columbia" I get three character values instead of one. Due to this my output vector is much longer than my input vector. Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You could use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5412122/2254210), which is going to work for every state but DC, because it's not a state. You'd have to add DC to the `state.abb` and `state.name` vectors manually.