# How do I replace multiple strings in a R dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a column in a data frame that is not well defined. For example, I have :

```
 > mydata$column1<-c("abcAppledef","gsApple123hilhj","stBananaewfs","sfesBanana123sfeft",
"stwefPearsfet","stwfePearabcseft","wefCarwefeEef","wefwaCarWFEe","wefaCarEFWefe")
```

I would like to re-define the column by replacing the strings with wildcard, and the outcome should be something like:

```
> mydata$column1<-c("Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Pear","Pear","Car","Car","Car")
```

I am using

```
> mydata$column1<-gsub('.*Apple.*','Apple',mydata$column1)

> mydata$column1<-gsub('.*Banana.*','Banana',mydata$column1)

> mydata$column1<-gsub('.*Pear.*','Pear',mydata$column1)

> mydata$column1<-gsub('.*Car.*','Car',mydata$column1)
```

But I have many different kinds of patterns, and I would need to apply this on multiple tables as well. Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Maybe a lookup table?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have at the start the complete list of target strings? E.g., `targets = c("Apple", "Banana", "Pear")`? If so I would just change strings where they are present for that. `for (fruit in targets) {x[grep(fruit, x) <- fruit}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this
[Remove numbers from alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590139/remove-numbers-from-alphanumeric-characters)

```
gsub('[0-9]+', '', x)
gsub('st', '', x)
```

I am afraid you would need to clean it in a series of gsub to get 100% clean data

Comment: Thanks. But 'st' was just an example, they don't really have patterns. I'll modify my quesiton.

Comment: you could invert the question..instead of looking at patterns to replace and clean, you could search for patterns in a few values(fruits)