# Remove all number from a column

Tags: r, regex

Using this it is possible to remove nbsp

```
str_replace_all(df$text, 'nbsp', '')
```

What kind of regex can someone use to remove all number with this command?

Comment: Can you give us some example data?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590139/remove-numbers-from-alphanumeric-characters depending on the example you provide

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Depending on the regex engine used you may just use `\D` which is the character class for everything but digits. Otherwise the regex could be `[^0123456789]` which matches anything not in the set. https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "nbsp" you're referring to a Non Breaking Space, then it should work by using explicit Unicode encoding.

The nbsp is encoded [as `0x00A0` in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), so on R you can express it as `"\U00a0"`.

For example:

```
> "This is a strange\U00A0 character"
[1] "This is a strange  character"
```

[image]

This might be more clear with a different character:

```
> "This is a strange \U00A1 character"
[1] "This is a strange ¡ character"
```

[image]

And this can be removed as you would expect.

```
> str_remove("This is a strange \U00A1 character", "\U00A1")
[1] "This is a strange  character"
> str_remove("This is a strange\U00A0 character", "\U00A0")
[1] "This is a strange character"
```

This also works by providing the decimal notation:

```
str_remove("This is a strange\U00A0 character", intToUtf8(160))
```

Note, this works on my computer, but there might be variations with locale settings and fonts installed.