# Remove from vector elements containing a number in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a few files that are named after rural properties like the following:

```
v1 <- c("Badger", "Hill", "Farm", "1.json")
v2 <- c("Buffalo", "Pass", "Farm", "2.json")
> v1
[1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm"   "1.json"
> v2
[1] "Buffalo" "Pass"    "Farm"    "2.json"
```

I managed to split the file name elements, but I want to keep only those which do not contain any number on it. The desired output would be:

```
> v1
[1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm"  
> v2
[1] "Buffalo" "Pass"    "Farm"
```

Quite simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove numbers from alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590139/remove-numbers-from-alphanumeric-characters)

Comment: @Maël I don't think that's a very good duplicate target. Here the question author wants to remove elements that contain a number. In the duplicate target, the question author wants to remove the numbers but retain the rest of the character strings. I searched a bit and couldn't find a good duplicate. If you find one, ping me and I'll close this. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30906571)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
v1 = v1[!grepl("[0-9]", v1)]
v2 = v2[!grepl("[0-9]", v2)]
```

`grepl` detects patterns, the regex pattern `[0-9]` will detect any digit.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_subset` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(v1, "^\\D+$")
[1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm" 
str_subset(v2, "^\\D+$")
[1] "Buffalo" "Pass"    "Farm"
```

---

Or in `base R` can specify `invert = TRUE` in `grep`

```
> grep("\\d", v1, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm"  
> grep("\\d", v2, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "Buffalo" "Pass"    "Farm"
```

Answer (score 2):

`"^(?!.*({{STRING}}))"` is a nice regex way of specifying `not`

````
v1 <- c("Badger", "Hill", "Farm", "1.json")
v2 <- c("Buffalo", "Pass", "Farm", "2.json")


grep("^(?!.*(\\d))", v1, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm"  

grep("^(?!.*(\\d))", v1, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm" ```
````

Answer (score 2):

We can try this

```
> grep("^\\D+$", v1, value = TRUE)
[1] "Badger" "Hill"   "Farm"  

> grep("^\\D+$", v2, value = TRUE)
[1] "Buffalo" "Pass"    "Farm"
```