# convert state names to abbreviations using grep

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, paste

My question is similar to this, but different:

[State name to abbreviation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411979/state-name-to-abbreviation-in-r)

I have a vector of state names, like so:

```
 bs <- c("texas", "tex", "calif", "wisc", "mass", "miss", "oh", "ohio", "colo", "fla")
```

Each entry in the vector above corresponds to a state name from `state.name`.  The problem is the entries in `bs` are not standardized.  I would like to use `bs` as an input vector and return the corresponding state abbreviation from `state.abb`.  The following code works sort of but not the way I want.

```
state.abb[grep(paste(bs, collapse = "|"), state.name, ignore.case = T)]
```

It returns:

```
"CA" "CO" "MA" "MS" "MO" "OH" "TX" "WI"
```

which is simply the UNIQUE state abbreviations.  What I want is:

```
c("TX", "TX", "CA", "WI", "MA", "MS", "OH", "OH", "CO", "FL)
```

Clearly I am missing something here.  I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions.  Any help would be much appreciated.

This question is updated from a prior version.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you can do something like:

```
a=nchar(state)>2 # Find those that have not been abbreviated yet:
```

Now you need to obtain the transformation matrix for those that they resemble. Ie have minimum distance with the `state.name` given in r.

```
b=attr(adist(state.name,state[a],counts=T,ignore.case = T),"trafos")
```

Using the transformation matrix, write a function to obtain the one with the maximum resemblance and replace them in the state vector:

```
fun=function(x) which.max(nchar(gsub("(^M+).*|.*","\\1",x)))
replace(state,a, tolower(state.abb[apply(b,2,fun)]))
[1] "va" "fl" "ca" "tx" "me" "ny" "il" "in" "ri" "az" "oh"
```

Comment: this is pretty inventive.  i like the levenshtein distance aspect of it though I worry about that "me" instead of "ma".

Comment: maybe it's because the edit distance between "ma" and "me" is the same so there's a tie?

Comment: No there is no tie.. if I use `mass` it doesnot recognize, while if I use `massa` it does recognize. I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

As a start I think you can just take the first 2 characters of each state. For most states that would be sufficient.

```
> df$state_final <- substr(df$state, 1 , 2)
> df$state_final
 [1] "va" "fl" "ca" "te" "ma" "ny" "il" "in" "ri" "ar" "oh"
```

Subsequently, for states like Texas that you want to be abbreviated as "tx" instead of "te", I think you need to manually recode these. At first you could identify what abbreviations need additional manipulation with this code:

```
df[!df$state_final %in% tolower(state.abb),]$state_final 
[1] "te"
```

And then do something likes this to recode the wrong abbreviations:

```
df$state_final <- car::recode(df$state_final, "'te' = 'tx'")
```

You could add more of these by adding a semicolon after 'tx', so like:

```
"'te' = 'tx' ; 'ao' = 'az'"
```

in case Arizona had been wrongly abbreviated as ao.

Comment: I get what you mean.  I kind of had that idea, but how would you know if something wasn't right?  my actual dataframe is very large.

Comment: With belowcode I think you can identify what states need additional replacement. This code only returns "te" in the sample of data you provided, what means you need additional code for the Texas abbreviation.

    
df[!df$state_final  %in% tolower(state.abb),]$state_final
    
[1] "te"

Comment: You know this is wri=ong since for texas its not `te` but `tx`... the abbrevations are not necessarily the two first letters

Comment: I know, I would just use that to identify what state abbreviations need additional manipulation. Subsequently, I would do something like this:
df$state_final <- car::recode(df$state_final, " 'te' = 'tx' ")

You could add more of these by adding a semicolon after 'tx'; like " 'te' = 'tx' ; 'ao' = 'az' "    in case Arizona was wrongly abbreviated as ao.

Comment: in the example above there would be an error because 'ar' is the abbreviation for 'arkansas' in `state.name`.

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize that. You could opt to do unique(df$state) at first to identify what states all need recoding. If the state names are really a blur, I think the only option is to put all "states" manually in the recode command with the right abbreviations.